# Benchmarking Apps created with feathers

Tags: benchmarking, feathersjs

Does anyone tried benchmarking / profiling an app created with [feathersjs](https://feathersjs.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [feathers-profiler](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-profiler) which logs service method calls (through any transport) and profile information. For gathering profiles the [debugging documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/advanced/debugging.html) should also give you more information.

Besides that any standard [webserver benchmarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server_benchmarking) tool will also work.

Comment: I tried `feathers-profiler` and it is amazing!

I still have a question though. When I tried profiling users authentication I start getting timeouts if I will try to authenticate more than 50 users. 

I found out that the bottleneck is the authentication service during `create`.

I am using ["jwt", "local"] for strategies.

I also tried overriding the timeouts on client side but still it doesn't help.

Comment: Hm, might be worth investigating more in an issue. More than 50 users at once or sequentially? How long is each token generation taking?

Comment: Sequentially.

```15:11:27 authentication::create (socketio) 5497.9 ms - 33 pending
    Error: Authentication timed out ...
```

Comment: I tried the the `DEBUG` and the only thing I can see that takes time is this 

...
`feathers-authentication-local:verify Verifying password +93ms
feathers-authentication-local:verify Verifying password +89ms
feathers-authentication-local:verify Verifying password +89ms`
...